# Correo no sale si no cierro el programa

Tags: vb.net, email

Saludos,

Estoy programando en VB a través de VS2017, hice un programa  que envía correo electrónico a las cuentas de correo que específico. El problema radica que el correo no llega a los destinatarios, solo llega cuando cierro la aplicación.

Agradecería cualquier ayuda, a continuación le muestro un resumen del código:

```
Dim _smtpMessage As New Net.Mail.MailMessage
Dim _smtpServer As New Net.Mail.SmtpClient
Dim _autenticationUser As String = "direccion@dominio.com"
Dim _autenticationPassword As String = "password"

_smtpServer.Host = "servidor.dominio.com" 'uso una cuenta de gmail
_smtpServer.Port = 587
_smtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(cuenta de correo, contraseña)
_smtpServer.EnableSsl = CBool(IIf(condicion = 1, True, False))
_smtpMessage.From = New Net.Mail.MailAddress(cuenta de correo)
_smtpMessage.Subject = "En prueba"
_smtpMessage.Body = "Contenido del mensaje"
_smtpConfig._Email01 = "direccion@dominio.com"
_smtpMessage.To.Add(_smtpConfig._Email01)
_smtpServer.Send(_smtpMessage)
```

Con todos los valores correctos el programa se ejecuta a la perfección, pero los correos no salen del programa si no cierro la aplicación...

Comment: ese es todo el codigo? no hay un send por algun lado?

Comment: Que version de .net estas usando? Tienes por casualidad instalado el antivirus de Norton?

Comment: gbianchi si ves la ultima linea hay esta el Send _smtpServer.Send(_smtpMessage)

Comment: Estoy usando Visual Studio 2017